# Order of adjectives in terms of characterizing the red beetroot as a raw material for scientific research

Tags: word-order

I have an issue with a proper description of red beetroot as a research material.

During my experiment the fresh red beetroot is grated in shreds.

Following such kind of treatment, does it become *the fresh grated red beetroot* or *the fresh red grated beetroot*? Consider that a red beetroot and a beetroot are synonyms.

Comment: Put the **red** last as it is the type of beetroot, subsequently grated. It remains to decide whether the beetroot is fresh, or its gratings. But you can simplify things. Having already established that you are working with **red** beetroot, there is no need to keep repeating that information.

Comment: red beetroot and grated/in shreds are two redundancies. You either grate something or you shred it but you don't "grate something in shreds". Also, I doubt you mean fresh; I think you mean raw (uncooked).

Comment: To grate a hard vegetable like a potato or beetroot is enough. versus: I shredded the paper by tearing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are confusing adjectives and adverbs.

When you say *grated* and put descriptive words in front of that word, those words normally end up acting as adverbs.

Although it's possible to argue for a flat adverb, the following would be more common:

> The **freshly** grated red beetroot.

You put adverbs before the verb and adjective after the verb but before the noun.

So, in the case of the previous sentence, you have this:

> The freshly<sup>adv</sup> grated<sup>verb</sup> red<sup>adj</sup> beetroot<sup>noun</sup>.

---

But you mean to use *fresh* as an adjective.

This would normally be expressed as:

> The fresh<sup>adj</sup> red<sup>adj</sup> beetroot<sup>noun</sup>.

If you add the verb *grated* to that sentence, the verb comes *before* everything else. So, it would become:

> The grated<sup>verb</sup> fresh<sup>adj</sup> red<sup>adj</sup> beetroot<sup>noun</sup>.

---

Based on this, here is your original sentence followed by your rephrased sentence:

> During my experiment, the fresh red beetroot was grated [into shreds].
>   → During my experiment, I grated the fresh red beetroot [into shreds].

---

Further, if you want to specify *fresh* as both an adjective ***and*** an adverb, you would say:

> During my experiment, I used freshly grated fresh red beetroot.

Comment: You would write grate into shreds and fresh beetroot? I think the OP means raw beetroot. Fresh beetroot as opposed to rotten beetroot??

Comment: @Lambie Those words make sense to me. *Fresh* can be used in contrast to *stale* (or *store bought*), and you can also grate something into [shreds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shred). (When I use my grater on cheese, I ends up with shreds of cheese.) The specific vocabulary (while possibly uncommon—although not to me) doesn't impact the syntax.

Comment: In English, we say to grate something. We don't generally mention shreds. Yes, you end up with shredded cheese. Not cheese in shreds. People just don't say that. They might say:my life is in shreds.

Comment: @Lambie It may be redundant, but it's perfectly understandable. In fact, if I wanted to specify how *long* I wanted the shreds to be (which I've had occasion to do in the past), I would *have* to say *grate it into* ***long*** *shreds* or *grate it into* ***short*** *shreds*.

Comment: Understandable does not mean that it is a usual style. I would never say grate into shreds and think my point is valid. Grating always produces shreds or strips of one type or another. It's redundant.

Comment: @Lambie But, again, redundant doesn't mean unacceptable or even necessarily uncommon. I would not think twice about hearing *grate into shreds*. People say *PIN number* all the time. It's perfectly natural. Even though saying *number* after *PIN* is redundant. It comes down to style—perhaps also regionalism and dialect. There are many things I wouldn't say that other people do. And vice versa, I'm sure.

Comment: The PIN number example is not the same at all. And regionalism has nothing to do with  it. He didn't use the beetroot during the experiment: he grated it as part of the experiment.

Comment: Lannie, in Britain, when we grate cheese, what we get is 'grated cheese". It is available in shops under that name.

Answer (score 1):

The standard order is: **opinion, size, physical quality, shape, age, colour, origin, material, type, purpose**.

Thus, delicious (opinion) tiny (size), **grated (physical quality)** oval (shape) **fresh (age) red (colour)** German (origin) beetroot

[Adjective order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order)